# DllOpen() can't open qpdf28.dll when using PDFtoPrinter

Tags: windows, pdf, cmd, printing

I am using [PDFtoPrinter.exe](http://www.columbia.edu/%7Eem36/pdftoprinter.html) to print PDF files via cmd line. But on some Windows computers, when executing the print command as shown in the documentation, an error occurs:

> "DllOpen() can't open
> C:\User\Admin\AppData\Temp\PDFPrinterTmp\qpdf28.dll".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSvlD.png)

I went to that folder and found that there is a .dll file, the file still has data, no errors. I have also used admin rights to do the print command, or register the DLL for the file, but the problem is still not fixed. I also used the command to check if any .dll files in the machine are missing or damaged, and as a result, no files are corrupted.

How to fix this problem?

Comment: this is the syntax of the statement that i make to print :

PDFtoPrinter filename.pdf "Name of Printer"

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs, because the microsoft redistributable package is missing in the correct version. I don't know which exact version is needed, but I simply installed the three currently supported version from the [official download page from microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170) for x86 and 64 bit and the problem is solved.